# scrolling UITableView to bottom in addition to resizing insets

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, scroll

so I have a UITableView that I need to scroll to the very last cell when the keyboard appears. Currently I listen for the UIKeyboardDidShow/Hide notifications and resize the insets to make the whole tableView be above the keyboard, and I attempt to scroll it down. The scrolling works if the tableView is at the very top when the keyboard appears, but if its scrolled somewhere in the middle of the list or at the bottom then it does not scroll all the way down and gets kind of messed up (I cant scroll past a certain point, just kind of janky in general).

Below is my code that runs when the keyboard is shown:

```
func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {

        // changes the content insets of the tableView to be above the keyboard
        let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size

        var contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize!.height, right: 0.0)

        var rate: NSTimeInterval = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue

        UIView.animateWithDuration(rate, animations: {

            self.commentsTableView.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.commentsTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        }, completion: { (value: Bool) in

            // scrolls to bottom
            self.scrollToBottom()

        })

    }
```

and here is the method that actually does the scrolling:

```
func scrollToBottom() {

        // scrolls to bottom
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: commentsTableView.contentSize.height - commentsTableView.bounds.size.height, width: commentsTableView.bounds.size.width, height: commentsTableView.bounds.size.height)
        commentsTableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
    }
```

does anyone know of a better way to accomplish this or see any problems with my current implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to change `contentInset` of the table in your case. Instead, change the height of the table, e.g. when `keyboardShown` function of your is called, cut the height equal to keyboard's height from your table's height, and when keyboard is gone, do the opposite. Good Luck!

Comment: alright, ill give changing the frame a shot. any reason why you think this approach is better?

Comment: same issue still, and it actually presents another issue in that I can keep scrolling the table view off screen for some reason. using the insets definitely looks cleaner/seems to work better

Comment: I think, you are changing `contentInset` of the table somewhere in your code in addition to the changing the frame, please, double check your code. I have used this approach a lot, and worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

This method works well for me:

```
NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: [dataSourceArray count]-1 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated: YES];
```

You can play around with with the scroll position to get the effect you're looking for, this tells the table to scroll to the last cell instead of to a specific CGRect.

Comment: I just realized your example is in Swift, but perhaps it would be easy to translate this?

Comment: yeah I can write it in swift, ill give it a shot. thanks

Comment: unfortunately that yields the same result. it must have something to do with the resizing of the tableView.